# What is more Efficient? Implementation in overloaded function or by checking object type in Base class function

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Overloaded a myFunction to have specific Logic to be Implemented in respective 
Class, but for Derived1 Class myFunction was not overloaded as I want to use the same functionality of Base Class.

```
Class Base
{
   public:
      virtual void myFunction() { }
}

Class Derived1 : public Base
{
   public:
}

Class Derived2 : public Base
{
   public:
      void myFunction() { }
}
```

OR

Same can be Achieved by Below Implementation, here I have added a member function to know the calling Derived class name, accordingly my logic will be executed in Base Class myFuncation.

```
enum DerivedClassType {
    Derived1 = 0,
    Derived2
};

Class Base
{
   public:
      void myFunction() {
        if(this->ClassType() == DerivedClassType::Derived1)
        { /*This logic is only for Derived1 Class object*/ }
        else
        { /*General Logic*/ }
      }
   protected:
      virtual DerivedClassType ClassType() = 0;
}

Class Derived1 : public Base
{
      virtual DerivedClassType ClassType() { return DerivedClassType::Derived1;}
}

Class Derived2 : public Base
{
      virtual DerivedClassType ClassType() { return DerivedClassType::Derived2;}
}
```

I have a scenario where I don't have most of the logic to remain same for both Derived1 and Derived2 Class, but only few extra logic I want to add for Derived1 Class. Hence I wanted to know which approach will be efficient to use.

Comment: For snippets to be equivalent, `myFunction` has to be made `virtual` in the first one. Then the first one should obviously be faster in most cases.

Comment: Do whatever is most clear for your design. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Can't say for certain, but I have a hard time seeing a string comparison being less expensive than a V-table (or whatever being used for `virtual`-backing deep magic) look-up. Time  a few billion iterations and see which is faster.

Comment: It's unlikely to matter one iota in any real program.

Comment: It is a common knowledge that implementation of compile-time polymorphism is best to be left to compiler, and home-brew solutions would be inferior.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Your two samples behave differently, possibly because of typos.

Comment: Consider using [curiously recurring template pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=curiously+recurring+template+pattern) for the compile time polymorphism.

Comment: I had a done a typo mistake, which I have corrected in my latest edit. Before it was completely different behavior in both the approaches, but now I believe it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many reasons - code maintainability, extensibility, concision, reliability, minimising the amount of code that needs to be recompiled/redistributed to pick up changes in some library code it uses - you should almost always use `virtual` functions rather that writing your own switching mechanisms.  If you need to ask about it on stackoverflow, I'd go as far as to say *always* prefer virtual functions until you understand all the implications and could be answering questions like this one.

That said, you're specifically asking what's more efficient, so lets say the importance of that eclipses all other considerations above.  Whenever you really have to care (your program's known to be too slow with real life data/inputs on the hardware that it needs to run on), then do try plausible alternatives and *measure* - things can vary with compilers, hardware, operating systems etc..

Is a `switch` plausibly better than `virtual` dispatch?  ***Yes***.  Switching can more efficient, but not if you're doing it with `std::string`s (which are expensive to compare), and especially not if you're having `ClassName()` create `string` temporaries (which require dynamic memory allocation each time).  If you instead used an `enum` with enumerators for the different classes, and a `switch` between them, and the functions to call can be inlined or even optimised away, then in my measurements I've seen an order-of-magnitude speed improvement over virtual dispatch.  If the functions you're calling do a non-trivial amount of work themselves, the speed of switching to them is likely to be an insignificant overhead.

Comment: I realized later, that using enum comparison should be a better approach rather using std::string comparison. Appreciate your answer and it really helped me clarify my doubt.